Intuitively, what does the $\color{red}{1}$ mean in $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{\color{red}{1}}{\left(\dfrac ba\right)}$?
For instance, let a be apples and b be berries. Then $\dfrac{a}{b}$ means $\dfrac{\text{apple}}{\text{1 berry}}$, and $b/a$ means $\dfrac{\text{berry}}{\text{1 apple}}$. But what does the red $\color{red}{1}$ below mean? What's the unit of $\color{red}{1}$?
$\dfrac{a}{b}  \quad = \quad \dfrac{\color{red}{1}}{\left(\dfrac ba\right)}$.
How do I explain this to a child? I am asking for intuition, NOT asking about rationalizing the denominator.

Do you have the same question about the 1 in 1/a?

@DanielWagner No. If s = # of slices of a pie, then $\dfrac{\color{red}{1}}{s} = \color{red}{1}$ slice, out of the pie.

The expression $\dfrac1{\dfrac ba}$ is nearly illegible, since it may be hard to tell it from $\dfrac{\dfrac1b}a.$ I would write either $\dfrac1{\left(\dfrac ba\right)}$ or $\dfrac1{b/a}. \qquad$

@MichaelHardy fixed

I strongly advise using a sentence as confusingly ambiguous as "let $a$ be apples and $b$ be berries". Is $a$ the number of apples? Or the quantity of fruits, expressed with a unit of apples? Or the value of an apple?

@Stef What's the best unit? number, quantity, or value? You are at liberty to edit my quesiton.

@Bes There is no "best unit". I am just pointing out an ambiguous wording in your question. I don't know what the two sentences "Let a be apple and b be berries. Then a/b = apple/(1 berry)" were supposed to mean, and I suspect that every person who reads these sentences will come up with a different interpretation of it.

The case where $a$ and $b$ have the same units may be a more convenient setting to explain the equation $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{b
}{a}}$. If I have $3$ apples and you have $4$ apples, then I have $3/4$ as many apples as you, or $75\%.$ That $3/4$ is a unitless ratio, since "apples" cancels with "apples". Reciprocation means we're flipping the perspective: you still have 4 apples and I have $3,$ so you have $4/3$ as many apples as me (approximately $133\%$). Since the $3/4$ and $4/3$ don't have units, neither does the $1$ in $3/4 = 1/(4/3)$, which makes sense: $1 = (3/4)\cdot(4/3)$. And if you include the units with all the 3s and 4s, you see it all cancels.

If you want the $1$ to have a unit, one option is
$$
\frac{a}{b} \textrm{ apples} = \frac{1 \textrm{ berry}}{\frac{b}{a} \frac{\textrm{berries}}{\textrm{apple}}}
$$
In words: "I am consuming $b$ berries for every $a$ apples I eat.  If I only eat $1$ berry, how many apples did I eat?"
However, I know from experience that getting too deep into these kinds of explanations often does more harm than good...

At what age do you want an explanation? in the age you still have apples and berries for fractions, you would not have double fractions. Later kids should know that dividing is complement to multiply.

@trula I pitched this particular answer to the poster, not a particular level of student.  I would expect the poster to adapt an explanation to whatever level of student they are teaching.

I wonder if this can be made more concrete with a food that always has a familiar constant number of some other food included? For example you can probably get a class to agree that if you ate half of a sandwich, you ate one slice of bread. Then you can write "$\frac{1}{2} \text{ sandwich} = \frac{1 \text{ slice of bread}}{\frac{2 \text{ slices of bread}}{1 \text{ sandwich}}}$?"

@ChrisCunningham other recipes also work for this.  Each batch of cookies calls for 3 cups of flour and 2 cups of sugar.  If I only have one cup of flour how much sugar should I use?  The problem is that naive reasoning is more direct than the compound fraction $\frac{2}{3} \textrm{ cups sugar} = \frac{1 \textrm{ cup flour}}{\frac{3 \textrm{ cups flour}}{2 \textrm{ cups sugar}}}$.

I interpreted this question to ask what the unit would be on the digit 1 if we write $\frac{a \ \text{apples}}{b \ \text{berries}} = \frac{1}{\frac{b \ \text{berries}}{a \ \text{apples}}}$. In that case, wouldn't it have to be unit-less, or something like $\frac{\text{apples}}{\text{apple}}$?

@NickC I agree, but this was my best attempt to interpret reciprocation of a fraction in a unitful context.
